# Dompdf arabic text alignment not working properly

Tags: html, css, alignment, arabic, text-align

As you can see, I set the alignment to `right` and put a border to see what is wrong with it. I need to put it in full right

[image: Screenshot]

this is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="lol">
    <span style="font-size:15px; border: 5px solid red;"> نحن مؤسسة رفيد السعودية, نفيد بأن المذكور أعلاه يعمل لدينا بوظيفة -----------, و ليس لدينا مانع من إيجاره شقة سكنية.  ونرجو منكم التعاون معه وتيسير أموره حيث ان اجراءات الاستقدام لعائلته تحت الاجراء . و لقد اصدرنا هذا الخطاب بناء على طلبه و دون ادنى مسؤولية على المؤسسة.

</span><br><br>
</div>
```

this is the CSS:

```
div.lol {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting direction to rtl. Alignment is not the same as direction. When you want to output Arabic you have to set the direction to rtl, otherwise the text will be right aligned but the position of commas and other punctuation characters won't be correct.

```css
div.lol {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately dompdf does not yet support RTL directionality.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. But still not working. I have tried this and a lot of codes to make it properly right aligned but no success.